# get number range

Tags: javascript, numbers

I'm not 100% sure how to ask this question so please dont mark me down for that.. I will do my best.

how do I work out what range my number falls in?

eg:

```
var range = 100;
var myNum = 320;
```

Therfore my result would be `300` as that is the range 320 falls into.

further exampes would be:

```
var range = 100;
var myNum = 190;

result: 100

var range = 100;
var myNum = 864;

result: 800
```

and lastly:

```
var range = 50;
var myNum = 864;

result: 850
```

Hope this make sence.

Comment: So what you want is the closest multiple smaller than the given number... "range" is something different IMO (like `50` is in the range of `0` and `100`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the logic you're looking for:

```
var result = range * Math.floor(myNum / range);
```

Replace `Math.floor` by `Math.ceil` if you want to find the upper bound of the "range".
The code above is an implementation of:

- How often does `range` suit in `range`?
- Multiply the previous result by `range`
- The final result equals the "number range".

Answer (score 5):

You can also subtract from `myNum` the [modulus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) of `myNum` by `range`:

```
var result = myNum - (myNum % range);
```

Answer (score 2):

`result = myNum - (myNum % range)`

myNum % range means "if I put range in my myNum as many times as I can, what integer will I have left?"

and you can subtract that from myNum and you get your result.